# How to change the character set in an SQL file?

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode

I have an SQL file that is not written by me, and I don't have any idea about it. I tried to upload this file to server, but the string data characters got scrambled.

```
INSERT INTO `Anstitu` (`Code_Anstitu`, `Name_Anstitu`)
VALUES (7, '?©?§?±U‡?§UŒ ?¹U…UˆU…UŒ ?³?§?®??U…?§U†');
```

There are 1,000,000 records like this and I have to find a real way. I know about `SET NAMES utf8` but it's useless.

Any ideas?

Comment: Er, what is that value *supposed* to be?  What bytes do you see in the file in their place (use a hexdump utility)?

Comment: I think it was arabic or persian. some middle east language.

Comment: @eggyal There is 5 undefined values in windows-1252, all continuation bytes in utf-8, which decode to `?` as a replacement

Comment: @eggyal well the other option is not to render at all or throw an error

Comment: I used hexdump and I get some thing like `23204475 6d702046 696c650d 0a230d0a`

Comment: @mehran: That's just the start of the file, representing `'# Dump File\r\n#\r\n'`; I was asking about the bytes that represent the string in question.

Comment: it is small version of file: [dump1.sql](http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1358719641)

Comment: Okay.  For others' reference, the above string is encoded as `0x3fc2a93fc2a73fc2b155e280a13fc2a755c592203fc2b955e280a655cb8655e280a655c592203fc2b33fc2a73fc2ae3f3f55e280a63fc2a755e280a0`.  @Esailija: Note that the first byte is `0x3f` which, if UTF-8, would still be `'?'`.

Comment: It would be *really* helpful if you knew what the value in one of those records was actually supposed to be!

Comment: @eggyal True, now that I see the raw bytes it looks like once upon a time there was a valid UTF-8 file, that was misinterpreted in some other encoding, then saved in some other encoding, ending in a file like this. So it can't be directly decoded to gain sensible results, especially with the lossy `?` replacements, it's kinda tough.

Comment: The file is screwed and not repairable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
INSERT INTO Anstitu (Code_Anstitu, Name_Anstitu)
VALUES (7, N'?©?§?±U‡?§UŒ ?¹U…UˆU…UŒ ?³?§?®??U…?§U†');
```

assuming that Name_Anstitu is nvarchar column?